# How to integrate USB integration in Unity Engine for Desktop application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, usb

Has anyone done any Unity project where USB communication is done? I have to do USB communication with a board to get sensor values. How can I go about doing this USB communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link .NET DLLs in Unity by adding them to the project (drag and drop worked, if I recall correctly). So, code your board access library in a Visual Studio project using .NET, exposing the API you need to use and add the DLL.
You will be able to access the contents of the DLL from your Unity code (although I have only done this with C#).

Of course, this only works on PC. For other platforms, I don't know if this is even possible.

EDIT: Minor correction.